# Turtle in python - Trying to get the turtle which move infinity in rectangle

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")


#-Turtle_box-
alex=turtle.Turtle()
alex.shape("turtle")
alex.speed(10)
alex.pensize(2)
alex.color("red")
#-Turtle_box_end-

#-Turtle_first-
sapa=turtle.Turtle()
sapa.shape("turtle")
sapa.speed(2)
sapa.pensize(2)
sapa.color("red")
#-Turtle_first_end-

#-Var&list-start-
liss=[]
#-Var&list-end-


#-Turtle_box_start-
alex.penup()
alex.forward(300)
alex.left(90)
alex.pendown()

for i in range(300):
    alex.forward(1)
    x=alex.position()
    liss.append(x)
for i in range(3):
    alex.left(90)
    for i in range(600):
        alex.forward(1)
        liss.append(alex.position())
alex.left(90)
for i in range(300):
    alex.forward(1)
    liss.append(alex.position())
#-Turtle_box_end-


#-Turtle_first_start-
for i in range(100000):
    sapa.forward(1)
    if sapa.position() in liss:
        sapa.left(150)

wn.exitonclick
```

Question: Turtle "alex" make rectangle (box) 600px*600px and write all coordinates in list liss. Then turtle "sapa" go forward and if turtle touch wall of rectangle he must turn to left 150 degrees. And turtle "sapa" must go infinity in rectangle, but in my program turtle turn to left one time then turtle don't see wall. Where's problem.

Comment: What does "go infinity" mean?

Comment: Turtle sapa must hit the wall and turn to 150 degrees, then he go forward until he hit the wall again and turn to 150 degrees again. And he must go infinity

Answer (score 2):

Because alex traces out a simple rectangle starting on whole number coordinates and moving 1 unit per step, all of the positions stored in `liss[]` are whole numbers. But after sapa has bounced once by 150 degrees his coordinates are no longer whole numbers, so they are unlikely to exactly match the values in `liss[]`.

The way around this is to use a modified position function that rounds the coordinates to an `int`. For example, put this function near the top of your program:

```
def int_position(t):
    x, y = t.position()
    return int(x + 0.5), int(y + 0.5)
```

Now change all your

`liss.append(alex.position())`

to

`liss.append(int_position(alex))`

and don't forget to fix `x=alex.position()` `liss.append(x)`

Now change the sapa stuff to

```
for i in range(100000):
    sapa.forward(1)
    if int_position(sapa) in liss:
        sapa.left(150)
```

FWIW, in my version of your program, I used `sapa.color("blue")` to make it easier to see what's going on.

Since you're using Python 2, you should change `range(100000)` etc, to `xrange(100000)`, as it's more efficient and uses **much** less RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Since all values in your list `liss` are whole numbers and after `sapa's` bounce, all coordinate values are in points(float values), you need to round off these values before comparing it with `liss` values.

Comment: Um, I just said that... And it's probably more efficient space-wise to store the coordinates as `int`, too.

Answer (score 0):

To make an infinite loop, just type:

```
while True:
    # your code
```

Comment: Hey there I find it rude to just delete a post but maybe you could add this as a comment to @PM2Ring's answer? You are correct and this part is missing from their answer but that answer is overall driving to the solution to the issue.

Comment: Hi, I didn’t delete any post, I must have pressed delete by accident or something. I don’t have any intentions of deleting something that can help someone else

Comment: lol I meant one of the options for triage that I have is to delete an answer. You didn't do anything wrong, but do please consider the rest of my remarks regarding making your answer a comment on the accepted answer. Later!